# How fast can you sort n elements in the range {1,2,...n^2) given storage space of O(n)?

Tags: sorting

I am thinking about using counting sort. But I don't think that's answer since k, in this case, is n^2. So the sorting time would be O(n+n^2). Also I think that would exceed the storage limit.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)?

Comment: @Makoto: when you pick a bad pivot for Quicksort, the running time would be O(n^2). Besides, I am given O(n) storage space, so I think I can use a sorting algorithm that requires some space.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but this appears to be a two-digit base-n radix sort which is therefore O(n). The first pass buckets on a[i]%n, the second pass buckets on a[i]/n. This requires O(n) auxiliary storage.

Comment: (PS this sounds a lot like homework, what with the very specific requirements on storage and unusual conditions; please tag as such if so.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [bottom-up merge sort](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_merge_sort) to achieve that, which runs in O(n log n), requiring no additional space (since it is in-place).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a slightly modified version of the [Merge Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) so that it splits the list into n parts instead of halves. The time complexity for the merge sort is O(n log n), but I don't know how to get the edited version's one.
If someone helps me I'll add it to my answer :)

**EDIT:**
It seems someone already invented this, see @JSPerfUnkn0wn's answer